# How to isolate read followed by insert in CosmosDb transaction?

Tags: stored-procedures, transactions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to implement locking in CosmosDb.

I have a stored procedure which tries to read a record, if record does not exist - it tries to create the record.

The problem is I get Conflict on insert (409) once in a while.

Here is my problematic stored procedure:

```
function tryLock(lockId, createdDate, ttl) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();

    var query = 'select * from root r where r.id = "' + lockId + '"';
    collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, {}, function(err, documents) {
        if (err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
        if (documents.length > 0)
        {
            var existingDocument = documents[0];
            var responseDoc = {locked: false, etag: existingDocument._etag, createdDate: existingDocument.createdDate };
            response.setBody(responseDoc);
        }
        else
        {
            createNewLockRecord();
        }
    });

    function createNewLockRecord() {
        let lockItem = {id: lockId, createdDate: createdDate, ttl: ttl};
        collection.createDocument(collectionLink, lockItem,
            function (err, createdDocument) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                response.setBody({locked: true, etag: createdDocument._etag, createdDate: createdDocument.createdDate});
            });
    }
}
```

My question is, is at possible at all what I'm trying to achieve?

If I change the order of operations, for example - try inserting first, if it does not succeed - read existing record, will it improve the situation?

Comment: 'The ID provided for a resource on a PUT or POST operation has been taken by an existing resource. Use another ID for the resource to resolve this issue. For partitioned collections, ID must be unique within all documents with the same partition key value.' This is official doc said about 409 conflict. If your error also came from duplicated id, I think you need to provide the way to generate your 'lockId' which used to be the value of id. If not, I think we need to figure out the cause of 409.

Comment: I don't have duplicate id, I'm working with the same id intentionally, because this is how locking should work. It is a lock for session storage. One request acquires the lock, another can not acquire the lock. But it is not working as intended. It queries for the lock, checks that it does not exist, and tries to create the lock (because this transaction assumes it is free to create a lock because it has checked that it does not exist yet). But now it fails, because some other transaction takes the lock, which it is should not be able to do.

Comment: Thanks and I got what you mean, in my opinion, the question turned to be that if there's a way to check there's a record with specific lock-id exists or there's a process creating the record with that lock-id. And to tell you the truth I haven't found a way on cosmos db, so my idea is trying to achieve the 'lock' in other place. I'm also curious about this situation, if you have any further progress, pls added here, thank you sir!

Comment: I've solved it with kind of 'spin lock', just retrying to call this stored procedure in hope it would eventually hit the unlocked state and it would create a record successfully. Initial implementation failed in aprox. 2% cases, but with 3 retries it fails only in 0.001% cases.

Comment: That sounds good sir, could u pls add your solution as the answer? Your idea is speical and I think it may help others in some terms.

Answer (score 0):

As @George provided, it haven't appeared a good solution to solve the problem of the 'lock', and 'spin lock' seems to be a choice.

--Copy from the comment: Just retrying to call this stored procedure in hope it would eventually hit the unlocked state and it would create a record successfully. Initial implementation failed in aprox. 2% cases, but with 3 retries it fails only in 0.001% cases.